# What are the implications of running a motor well above its rated frequency?

Tags: electromagnetism, applied-physics

Plenty of material on the web will tell you what to expect when you run a 50/60Hz 3-phase induction motor at 60-80Hz, but what if you would like to run it at 140Hz? or 250Hz? Or at any frequency?

Currently we have a 50Hz motor which drives a conveyor via a chain arrangement that gears up by a factor of 2.8 (not by design; more by putting together what was readily available). Since our conveyor represents (as we understand it) a constant torque load, would we not be better off eliminating the chain arrangement with its friction losses, and just directly driving the motor at 140Hz? Would the loss of torque at higher frequency be cancelled out by the elimination of the gearing? Is there anything (dangerously) wrong with trying this?

Comment: From Beaty's Electric Motor Handbook: "5.19.2 Voltage and frequency variations NEMA MGl allows a variation of ±10% of rated voltage at rated frequency, ±5% of rated frequency at rated voltage, or a combination of rated voltage and frequency of 10%, provided that the frequency variation does not exceed ±5%. It is assumed the performance of the motor may differ from that at rated voltage and frequency conditions when operated at other than rated conditions."

Comment: [This page](http://cr4.globalspec.com/thread/58585) gives some interesting observations... but opinion seems divided over whether heating will become more or less of a concern. It suggests that extending well beyond the rated range depends on the load. The point of the question is to clarify these dependencies, at least in this one particular case.

Comment: For what it is worth, we decided to cautiously try directly driving the motor at up to 140Hz. It performed worse than the geared arrangement in that it seemed to reach a current limit at a lower speed. We can't explain why that would be.

Comment: I _think_ this is off topic here, as it's a technical question about a device, not a conceptual question about a physical principle.

Comment: electronics.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place.